# Why does not work toast message android 7

Tags: android

In Android 7, Toast message does not appear at all. However, in Android 5 and 6 it's working.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Where are you trying to show a toast? Meaning is it in an activity, fragment, service?

Comment: Main Activity, one button, button click , Toast.  ,

Comment: Thank you for the update Omer. Added a possible answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First try to reinstall your app. It can be a debbuging problem.

If this doesn't help 
try this:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: @OmerUcansu Wich phone do you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button mbut=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);
    mbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Passing the activity as the context.